# Differentiating Bezier curve spline matrix.

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, bezier-curve

So I know one (obvious) way to differentiate the cubic bezier curve point function P(t) = GBT:

expand the terms (B * T), differentiate them, collect the coefficents and then form the coefficent matrix (spline matrix) B again but I'm wondering if there's and easier way to go about this (namely, how to find B' without having to expand the terms GT out every time I want to differentiate and find P'(t). Essentially I want a way to find B' in the easiest (and fastest) way and I'm wondering if a method exists for something like this.

$$P(t)=\pmatrix{P1 & P2 & P3 & P4} *  
\pmatrix{  1 & -3 & 3 & -1 \\
  0 & 3 & -6 & 3  \\
  0 & 0 & 3 &-3 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1} * 
\pmatrix{1\\t\\t^2\\t^3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just differentiate the T so that it becomes $T'(t)=<0, 1, 2t, 3t^2>$ and $P'(t)=GBT'(t)$